# postfix not going to address on same domain with gmail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I am using postfix and gmail small business apps

It seems to be working great for sending email to external domains, but does not work when trying to send to email with same domain

So for example info@mysite.com sends to john@yahoo.com no problem
However, info@mysite.com does not send to chris@mysite.com

The question is if there is a problem with my postfixc config file?

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS client parameters
## The certificate authority file below is in the default location for Ubuntu,
## and is used by Postfix to validate the CA used by Google's mail servers
## for when Postfix talks to them to send mail
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom


# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mysite.com, ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal, localhost.us-west-2.compute.internal, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only


## These settings tell Postfix where to find the username and password to use
## when relaying e-mail through the server set in the relayhost directive above
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

Comment: So you're trying to relay from your postfix host through gmail? What do your postfix logs say?

Comment: I'm actually receiving email and the mx records appear correct. The problem is when I send email from the server (php) to someone on the same domain. I suspect that the same domain name is keeping the email internal, but not sure how to configure this correctly for external delivery.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding things correctly, mail for mysite.com is handled by Google Apps. Is this correct?

If so, you should not have mysite.com in your `mydestination` list. Per [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination), entries in that list will be delivered locally, not relayed out to other mail systems.